# Decimal ages in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate decimal ages based on dates of birth and a recent date.  I have the following test dataframe.

```
df.1 <- structure(list(dob = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0
), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 
                                             0L, 0L), mday = c(18L, 24L, 25L, NA, 31L, 15L), mon = c(11L, 
                                                                                                     5L, 11L, NA, 11L, 11L), year = c(100L, 101L, 102L, NA, 99L, 101L
                                                                                                     ), wday = c(1L, 0L, 3L, NA, 5L, 6L), yday = c(352L, 174L, 358L, 
                                                                                                                                                   NA, 364L, 348L), isdst = c(0L, 1L, 0L, -1L, 0L, 0L), zone = c("GMT", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "BST", "GMT", "", "GMT", "GMT"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), recent.date = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                ), hour = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), mday = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              3L, 1L, 2L), mon = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), year = c(114L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), wday = c(2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             1L), yday = c(153L, 152L, 154L, 153L, 151L, 152L), isdst = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), zone = c("BST", "BST", "BST", "BST", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "BST", "BST"), gmtoff = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), .Names = c("sec", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "zone", "gmtoff"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("dob", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "recent.date"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Using the lubridate function and decimal date, I am trying to convert the dates to decimal dates:

```
library(lubridate)
df.1$decimal.dob <- decimal_date(df.1$dob)
df.1$decimal.recent.date <- decimal_date(df.1$recent.date)
```

However because I have missing dates of birth, when I try to convert the dates of birth to decimal ages, I get an error.  I therefore can't take the 'decimal.recent.date' column away from the 'decimal.dob' column to give me a decimal age.

If anyone could help me getting this to work, I would very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

So search for and remove the `NA` entries.  I'm assuming that if there's an `NA` in, say, `dob$sec[j]`, then `dob$min[j]` is also `NA` and so on.

```
killit <- which (is.na(dob$sec))
foo <- decimal_date(df.1$dob[-c(killit)])

#[1] 2000.962 2001.477 2002.981 1999.997 2001.953
```

You'll have to shrink your `df.1$decimal.dob` to have the same length as the reduced input set.

Comment: Many thanks @Carl Witthoft - but is there anyway of keeping my dataframe intact?  There is lots of data that we ideally want to keep in the dataframe and I was hoping that I could use an ignore na command?

Comment: I think you could do `df.1$decimal.dob[-c(killit)] <- decimal_date(df.1$dob[-c(killit)])`  .  Try that and see if the dataframe remains as-is.